# Checking if file exists to launch different programs

Tags: macos, bash, file, shell

I use the following code to check for a file named `loaded` in the shared folder.This works when the file is placed in the local dir but it does not write the file to the shared folder.
What I'm i doing wrong?

```
file=“/Users/shared/loaded”
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
./app1
else
echo 'Installed' >"$file"
./app2
```

Comment: Does the user which runs that script have permissions to create files in `/Users/shared`?

Comment: Also: I fixed the quotes in your command script. If they really were the ones which appeared there, then that will be your problem, since bash will treat typographic quotes as ordinary characters.

Comment: @rici Thant was indeed the problem.Solved it already.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah. Maybe you should revert the edit, then. Or did you mean that permissions were the problem?

Comment: @rici Not the permissions,the quotes.I had used text edit early switched to text wrangler app and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "stat" `/Users/shared/loaded` you need execute permission on both `/Users` and `/Users/shared` directories.